# Access to SQL Server through .Net web application

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server

I am looking for a quick way to create a web application that accesses an SQL server database and displays tables of choice, enabling me to create new entries in those tables.

Any built in frameworks in Visual Studio 2017 that can be used? Or other easy to use ones?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the most simple way to create website that performs simple CRUD maintenance on database tables is to use MVC scaffolding, which will generate simple screens and code to work with data.  There's a nice "how to" blog entry at https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/asp-net/using-scaffolding-to-create-mvc-applications-with-visual-studio/